# How can I change the color of the intersections between circles?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I can draw the following figure, by adapting code by Stefan Kottwitz.

[image]

But, I need the color of the intersection of the disks is the same color as the background, as in the following examples.

[image]

Comment: Well, is it possible to translate the first sentence to English please? This is not `Portuguese.SX!

Comment: A possible translation: I know how to do the following figure, because I did an adaptation of a figure made by Stefan Kottwitz in this same site.

Comment: Fill circles with `even odd rule` like this `\fill[even odd rule] (0:1) circle(2) (120:1) circle(2) (-120:1)  circle(2);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple with `even odd rule`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[cyan] (-3,-3) rectangle (3,3);
    \draw[fill=red,even odd rule] (-1,0) circle (1.5cm) (1,0) circle (1.5cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[cyan] (-3,-3) rectangle (3,3);
    \draw[fill=red,even odd rule] (-1,0) circle (1.5cm) (1,0) circle (1.5cm) (0,-1) circle(1.5cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]